# How to run a function at regular intervals?

Tags: python, django

I have a DashboardData model. I get some info from this form and according to the given answers, I run a function by using form answers as parameters.

I want to run this function like `functions.myFunction(n_user, n_password, n_url, n_port, db_password)` with user's `DashboardData` values every 15 minutes. How can I run a function with parameters

How can I rerun it at regular intervals?

This is my form model:

```
class DashboardData(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True) # request.user
    n_username = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    n_password = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    n_url = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    n_port = models.IntegerField()
    period = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    db_password = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
```

And this is my function:

```
class myFunction():
    def __init__(self, n_user, n_password, n_url, n_port, db_password):
        self.zaman = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        self.location = a_url
        self.static_fields = {}
        self.index_name = "vulns-" + self.zaman
        self.download_all(n_user, n_password, n_url, n_port, db_password)
        self.send_it()
```

I tried to use apscheduler app but I cannot run it.

Comment: Try [django-celery-beat](https://github.com/celery/django-celery-beat)

Answer (score 0):

for example

```
from tkinter import *
import time
root = Tk()
root.title("DIGITAL CLOCK")
root.geometry("550x100")
root.config(bg="black")


def time_update():
    label_base.config(text=time.strftime("%I:%m:%S %p"))
    label_base.after(1000, time_update)


label_base = Label(root, text="123", font=("Axlongscreen_Font-Light", 
50), bg="black", fg="white", pady=20)
label_base.pack()
time_update()
mainloop()
```

if you create two or more function and want to one function to another then assing variable then in next line ad .after end of your variable name then inside parenthesis give interval duration as per milisecond and after comma give define function name which you want to run
I gave text.after(milisecond then time_update) because time_update where I want to return after 1000 milisecond. if you want to jump another function then you can give another function name

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/getting-started/introduction.html), I have included the links to the docs here.
It's pretty simple to configure it will allow you to schedule your tasks in the background.